# trying to add a textfield into an nsmenuitem but it wont show up

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

here is the code i use to try to add a textfield into an nsmenuitem

```
class menuitemtest1: NSTextField {
  var menuitemtest1 = NSTextField()
  override func viewDidChangeBackingProperties() {
    menuitemtest1.frame = CGRect(x: 220, y: 8, width: 103, height: 17)
    menuitemtest1.stringValue = "Maximum Lenght"
    menuitemtest1.isEditable = false
    menuitemtest1.textColor = .gray
    menuitemtest1.isSelectable = false
    menuitemtest1.drawsBackground = false
 }
}
```

thats the class
and how i add it

```
    var textFieldInMenutest = NSMenuItem()
    menuBarMenu.addItem(textFieldInMenutest)
    textFieldInMenutest.view = menuitemtest1()
```

Comment: Why does class `menuitemtest1` have a property `menuitemtest1`? `viewDidChangeBackingProperties` could be too late to set the frame.

Comment: isnt that how you wrap a textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an NSTextField subclass which has as a property, a separate and direct NSTextField instance. This makes no sense. What you *intended* to do, was this:

```
class menuitemtest1: NSTextField {
  override func viewDidChangeBackingProperties() {
    self.frame = CGRect(x: 220, y: 8, width: 103, height: 17)
    self.stringValue = "Maximum Lenght"
    self.isEditable = false
    self.textColor = .gray
    self.isSelectable = false
    self.drawsBackground = false
 }
}
```

As for why it "doesn't show up" — the text field you did add as the menu item's view has a zero-sized (default) frame, so it's simply invisible.

Further, `viewDidChangeBackingProperties` is not the correct place to set up basic properties of the field. In such a subclass, you should use the *initializer*, `init(frame:...` or `init(coder: ...`